# Element [0] of my array can't hold any number, it restarts to 0

Tags: arrays, c, loops, vector

My code is in spanish, but its understandable for anyone. What i was trying to do was to store diferent values (given by a random person) into an array. But whenever i scan the number suppoused to be stored in vector[0] i dont have any trouble to do that. But why i need to scan another element ej vector[1], my [0] element overwritten or something like that and setted to 0.

```
int main()
{
    int tamano;
    int posicion=0;
    int vector[50];
    char respuesta[2];
    printf("Desea Agregar un Vector?(si/no):");
    scanf("%s", respuesta);
    while(strcmp(respuesta, "si")==0||strcmp(respuesta, "SI")==0||strcmp(respuesta, "sI")==0||strcmp(respuesta, "Si")==0){
        printf("Agregue una componente a su vector: ");
        scanf("%d", &vector[posicion]);
        printf("Desea seguir agregando componentes?(si/no): ");
        scanf("%s",respuesta);
        posicion++;
    }
    tamano=posicion;
    for(int i=0; i< tamano;i++){
        printf("%d, ", vector[0+i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried by using a variable intead of a number in vector lenght in a very first time. Then i changed it because i thought it could be the problem. I have also tried by setting my "posicion" variable to 1 (means position) and it works fine. But whenever i try to use the [0] element it keeps on restarting in some way and setting down to 0.

```
type here
```

Comment: `char respuesta[2];` is only big enough to hold 1 char and a null terminator. It is too small to accommodate "si" 1) Make it longer. 2) specify a max field width to scanf so that you don't overrun it if the user types more than you are prepared for.

Comment: thx man it worked somehow. I didn't understood exactly why my variable "vector" is related with "respuesta". But anyway thank you i ll research on my own why this happens :D

Comment: Buffer overrun. You were writing into memory past the end of respuesta with your scanf's - so overwriting something else. It seems that the compiler put  your "vector" in memory after respuesta. The null terminator from "si" was overflowing into the beginning of vector. If the user typed a really long word, it could have affected multiple elements of vector.

Comment: OHHHHH. Now i get it. Thank you for real appreciate your answer :D.